# How to construct a key in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have to request a url with a passing key.
Like this:

```
/AVL_Request?Key=12591_CNB_YPR_2A_GN_1-8~12591_CNB_YPR_3A_GN_1-8~
```

I have to construct a key same pattern as above.
How do I construct the key in python?

Comment: Don't abuse the caps lock key!

Comment: Your question is unclear, an example does not define a pattern. Once you have the actual pattern defined and you still have problems defining this in Python (why use an ancient version, btw?), come back and ask for specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every pattern has its rules...

your question is too vague since you dont tell us if the first 5 numbers are random, the 3 following letters always have to be CNB, the last number should always be 8? Or maybe divisible by 2?

Got my point?

Anyway you can just `key = var1 + var2 + var3 + ... + varN` to construct your key.

But again, you must discover what rules were used in that key and find a way to replicate that pattern over and over again..

### Example:

```
var1 = '12591'
var2 = 'CNB'
var3 = 'YPR'
var4 = '2A'
var5 = 'GN'
var6 = '1'
var7 = '8'
var8 = '3A'

key = (
    var1 + "_" + var2 + "_" + var3 + "_" + var4 + "_" + var5 + "_" + var6 + "-" + var7 + "~" +
    var1 + "_" + var2 + "_" + var3 + "_" + var8 + "_" + var5 + "_" + var6 + "-" + var7 + "~")

print key
```

Comment: Thanks it's Working. But I have to print number of time same pattern.
So what should I do?

Comment: @RiteshMathur, if my answer helped you, please vote it up ;-). So.. back to your question... you can use a `for` loop to print `n` times... but i suggest you take a look at [codecademy](http://codecademy.com) and [learn python the hard way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/) to learn some basic python stuff..

Comment: Actually I am getting a response from the server in a list.
and I have to make that response in the same form as I defined above.
could you please help me on that